# Azure Active Directory Licensing of Students in O365 A3

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

Our school has students on an E3 licensing for education. Each student is (can be) licensed with:

- Azure Active Directory Basic for EDU
- Azure Active Directory Premium for EDU
- Azure Rights Management

All of these show "for student use benefit".

Why would a student need this access? What access is this giving them? I've searched on MS O365 site and no answers are found. I understand why *I* need these, but not a student.

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you have O365 A3 plan, all the users under your tenant will have an **Azure Active Directory Free** license.

Your E3 licensing for education also provides the three licenses:

- Azure Active Directory Basic for EDU
- Azure Active Directory Premium for EDU
- Azure Rights Management

**Azure Active Directory Basic** and **Azure Active Directory Premium** will have more services for the users.

You can see details from [Azure Active Directory pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/). Note: **Azure Active Directory Basic** is retired. You can refer to **OFFICE 365 APPS edition** instead.

**Azure Rights Management** is used protect important data by using applications and services that support this information protection solution. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/activate-service).

Whether to assign the above licenses to students depends on your needs. You can manage the Azure AD licenses in O365 admin center or Azure portal.